# Is there a way to better way to get outerHtml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get a consistent, cross browser outerHtml for a jQuery element, particularly `$("html").outerHtml()`. For example if the page source is this:

```
<html><script src="blah.js"></script><div class="foo"   id='bar'></p></div></html>
```

I want to be able to use `$("html").outerHtml();` to get the HTML string including the element itself, which would be:

```
<html><script src="blah.js"></script><div class="foo" id="bar"><p></p></div></html>
```

I've been using Brandon Aaron's [outerHtml plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml/) which looks something like this:

```
return $('<div>').append($("html").first().clone()).html();
```

However this seems to actually try to reload any externally referenced files in the document (scripts, stylesheets), which seems pretty excessive just to get the HTML source of a wrapper element. Can Javascript even put an HTML element inside a DIV element?

Locally, I get this error. Something to do with AJAX rules?

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/demo.js?_=1311466511031. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is there a better way to get outerHtml? I'd really like to avoid any network calls when doing this.

Comment: Are you certain you don't want the *inner* HTML of `body`?  What is your intended purpose with this data?

Comment: Yes very certain. I'm validating HTML or HTML fragments. Yes I know it's not the same as the HTML source.

Comment: You can always do a separate HTTP request for the location of the document when looking to parse the HTML in general.  However, that doesn't solve the issue for fragments.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to use both methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrote my own solution, which simply renders the wrapping element:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.outerHtml = function() {
    if (this.length == 0) return false;
    var elem = this[0], name = elem.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (elem.outerHTML) return elem.outerHTML;
    var attrs = $.map(elem.attributes, function(i) { return i.name+'="'+i.value+'"'; }); 
    return "<"+name+(attrs.length > 0 ? " "+attrs.join(" ") : "")+">"+elem.innerHTML+"</"+name+">";
  };
})(jQuery);
```

https://gist.github.com/1102076

Comment: Your solution forgets to feature detect for `el.outerHTML`. Sure it's non-standard but at least it's faster.

Comment: Oh thanks, so I just need to add: `if (elem.outerHTML) return elem.outerHTML;`?

Comment: and thorough testing that your shim returns HTML in the same format as `outerHTML`. i.e. outerHTML might return tags in uppercase, etc..

Comment: I think I will match the behaviour of `.html()` and `.innerHTML` which return uppercase tags in IE, and lowercase in real browsers.

Comment: I think that aswell but I know what IE is like, it does whatever it pleases and never makes sense. Thoroughly test it.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery outerHTML plugin from https://github.com/darlesson/jquery-outerhtml uses browser's native outerHTML when existent, as second option clone the nodes in a temporary document fragment and return its innerHTML or uses jQuery clone solution similar to Brandon Aaron's plugin.

This plugin might help you avoid the load of the reference files. In my tests in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer the issue did not happen calling the code below in a page with external JavaScript files.

```
    var outerHTML = $(document.documentElement).outerHTML();
```